# Angular 9 first build takes long, it is inconvenient for CI, is there a way to speed it up?

Tags: angular, continuous-integration, angular-ivy

Angular 9 has to compile some node_modules to make them work with Ivy. The compilation (by default) happens during the first build. That's ok on a developer machine because the first build happens only once. But that's inconvenient for CI. Because during the CI process (in GitLab for example) the environment gets created from scratch, it installs the node_modules and builds the project and the build is always the first long one.

Do you have any ideas how to speed it up?

Comment: Maybe [this Nrwl webinar about Nx](https://pages.ng-conf.org/nx-cloud-webinar/?utm_source=ng-conf+%24newswire&utm_campaign=15ba6d1380-EMAIL_CAMPAIGN_2020_02_21_03_49_COPY_01&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_eb2e5da0a1-15ba6d1380-120246923) that will happen on May, 21st, can fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my previous project is caching the `node_modules` folder based on `package-lock.json` hash.